# Delete file from Internal Storage in Adapter class in android

Tags: android, storage, android-adapter, delete-file

I want to delete selected files from phone storage in android. I have tried some ways but it is not working, there is no error as well.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyHolder>{
boolean isEnable = false;
List<ItemFiles> selectList = new ArrayList<>();


public MyAdapter.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout._main,parent,false); 
   return new MyViewHolder(view);

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int
        position) {   
                  public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                        int id = item.getItemId();

                        switch (id) {
                            case R.id.delete:
                                for (ItemFiles v : selectList) {
                                   File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ v);
                                   boolean file = dir.delete();
                                    if (file) {
                                        return true;
                                    } else {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }

}
```

There is no method such as getFileDir() showing in the adapter class. I am unable to find the right solution. It would be of great help, thanks.

Comment: `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ v);` Please give some examples of values for `dir.getAbsolutePath()`. And are they directories or files? Use dir.exists() to check if the diectory or file exists before you try to delete it. Why are you naming the return value of dir.delete() 'file'? Very confusing.

Comment: They are actually files and v is the selected file. I actually tried one of the solution and I do not know how to delete in adapter. If you could suggest that would be great.

Comment: Well give examples. And use dir.exists()_. Put it in the code. Adapt the code here too. And use another name.

Comment: `There is no method such as getFileDir() showing in the adapter class` You did not make clear why you wanted to use getFilesDir().

Comment: I have seen methods of how to delete file from storage and File dir = getFileDir() was the common way to do so.

Comment: That makes no sense. Now please give all info i asked for if you want to solve your problem.

Comment: Basically i want delete the items when I click delete button as given above. The common way to delete file in android  is  File dir = getFilesDir();
File file = new File(dir, "my_filename");
boolean deleted = file.delete(); but since getFilesDir() is not showing in adapter class. I don't know how I can delete in this class on click of delete button. I just want to delete the items that are selected when delete button is clicked.

Comment: That certainly is no common way. You are just repeating what you already told. I repeat too: give the info i asked for.